# bash: ./sublime_text: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, sublime-text

After installing Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 14.04 by coping the extracted files to `/opt`, I tried running Sublime Text using `./sublime_text`.

However it is giving an error `No such file or directory` when though `ls` tells us that it exists! What's going on?

```
x@x-ubuntu:/opt/sublime_text_3$ ls -l
total 11660
-rw-rw-r-- 1 x x    4696 Dec 16 22:28 changelog.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 x x  171056 Dec 16 22:28 crash_reporter
drwxrwxr-x 7 x x    4096 Dec 16 22:28 Icon
drwxrwxr-x 2 x x    4096 Dec 16 22:28 Packages
-rwxrwxr-x 1 x x 4172952 Dec 16 22:28 plugin_host
-rw-rw-r-- 1 x x 2582934 Dec 16 22:28 python3.3.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 x x   18883 Dec 16 22:28 sublime_plugin.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 x x   30672 Dec 16 22:28 sublime.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 x x 4932736 Dec 21 21:57 sublime_text
-rw-rw-r-- 1 x x     532 Dec 16 22:28 sublime_text.desktop

x@x-ubuntu:/opt/sublime_text_3$ ./sublime_text
bash: ./sublime_text: No such file or directory
```

Comment: is `sublime_text` a script file?

Comment: Run this command `bash sublime_text`

Comment: Please specify what extracted files you're talking about. I assume you downloaded [this](http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/sublime_text_3_build_3059_x64.tar.bz2) but please clarify. Is there any particular reason you did not use the .deb file instead? I just tried and cannot reproduce this. What happens if you try `file ./sublime_text`?

Comment: post the output of `file sublime_text`

Comment: Yes it was a 32bit binary being run in 64 bit Ubuntu

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu? It could be that you downloaded the wrong version of Sublime Text. That error message is the message you get when you try and run the 32-bit binaries under 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are trying to run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system. If you download the proper package for your system, it should work. If you don't know if your computer is 32-bit or 64-bit, try running

```
getconf LONG_BIT
```

(actually this checks if you're running 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu, to actually check if your hardware is 32-bit or 64-bit run:

```
grep -o -w 'lm' /proc/cpuinfo | sort u
```

and if one of the flags listed is 'lm' you have a 64-bit processor.)

Comment: Nice first answer!